# With Unity2019 for android build,no splash and BLACK SCREEN error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I am a beginner and finally trying to launch my app built with Unity3d(v 2019.2) to Play store.

I tried to build .abb file and exported Android project to get Google App Singing. And I succeed to register my App signing on Google console web.

Before this process, my app was worked well but I now see the black screen without a splash Unity logo.

After the black screen, I can see the touch event log as xxx0, 1 by logcat when I touched on the screen.

And the other thing I see that is the app is forced termination.

(I wonder I accidently pressed some setting checkboxes without knowing)

Please help.

Comment: I can not see a question here... What is your question, also please refer to [minimum, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. My question is how to solve stuck on the black screen brefore splash logo shows.

Comment: Does this happen on all device or only some devices ?

Comment: I only have a Samsung Galaxy 6s so I tried this one only. Is it possible some devices dependant?

Comment: Try installing virtual emulator, BlueStack and install your app. Check if its also happening in there. Also edit your question and add some images of build settings.

Comment: It also happens on BlueStack.